# How can I associate centrality score of genes(vertices) in a GRN with the probabilistic model in terms of cause and effect?

Tags: gene, gene-expression, networks, transcriptome-regulation

I'm learning to build Bayesian Network Based Modeling of Gene Regulatory Network of Cancerous Cellular Cells. So far, I have learned to form a Bayesian Network based on nature of genes(i.e Functional Genes and TFs). However, I cannot figure out how to give probability to each node/vertex. Is it possibile to somehow iterpret the centrality score of each vertex an associate the meaning with the probabilistic model in terms of cause and effect?

or can you atleast refer me a relevant research paper?

I believe I would be worth mentioning that I'm fairly new to this.

Here's my data of TFs and Sources.

| TF | Target | Model of Regulation | References |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABL1 | BCL2 | Repression | 11753601 |
| AHR | FOS | Unknown | 10478842 |
| APC | BIRC5 | Unknown | 11751382 |
| AR | ERBB2 | Activation | 21613411 |
| AR | ERBB2 | Unknown | 21741601 |

Following is the sample of my data for network analysis, mostly containing centrality scores some graph properties.

| SUID | name | BetweennessCentrality | ClosenessCentrality | ClusteringCoefficient | Eccentricity | EdgeCount | Indegree | IsSingleNode | NeighborhoodConnectivity | Outdegree | PartnerOfMultiEdgedNodePairs | selected | SelfLoops | shared name | Stress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7228 | TP53 | 0.06611272 | 0.46456693 | 0.04141865 | 4 | 75 | 50 | FALSE | 14.40625 | 25 | 11 | FALSE | 0 | TP53 | 39572 |
| 6788 | AR | 0.03605041 | 0.40410959 | 0.03164983 | 4 | 60 | 46 | FALSE | 13.38181818 | 14 | 5 | FALSE | 0 | AR | 20498 |
| 7029 | MYC | 0.03342125 | 0.35014837 | 0.03280053 | 5 | 81 | 74 | FALSE | 12.93589744 | 7 | 3 | FALSE | 0 | MYC | 19140 |